# connectionString c# doesn´t works

Tags: c#, connection-string

I have a problem withthe connectionString I think.

I have this:

```
public List<Usuario> getUsuario()
{
    List<Usuario> usuarios = new List<Usuario>();

    string strConn = ConfigurationManager
                        .ConnectionStrings["BDLocal"]
                        .ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn))
```

and in the web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add 
    name="BDLocal" 
    connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-EJ\SQLEXPRESS;Initial 
    Catalog=Crud.Data;Persist Security Info=True;User 
    ID=user;Password=pass"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
  />
</connectionStrings>
```

But the message I get when I go to api/usuario is:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
> System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettingsCollection.this[string].get returned null.

I know there must be something I'm doing wrong but I don´t know what it is.

Comment: This is a configuration problem, not a SQL Server problem.

Comment: How do you host your application? Do you have `web.config` file in your application folder?

Comment: Yes. I have a web.config file. and inside i have the connectionString configured as above

Comment: What .Net version are you using? Newer Asp.Net versions don't use web.config anymore

Comment: 4.0? i used the "reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP"" command

Comment: what version does your csproj file show, baconitus? (targetframeworks) do you have an appsettings.json file in this project? show us any configurationbuilder related code (perhaps in Program.cs or Startup.cs)

Comment: I dont have an appsetings.json. I edited the question with more of the code